# navigation through JqueryUI tabs using <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I found out on several articles that it is possible to navigate JqueryUI tabs using a button or  tag.

I am using this simple method

```
    $("#vtabs").tabs();

    $("#tabsinner").tabs();

    $(".changeTab").click(function() {
        alert("asdas");
        var selected = $("#tabsinner").tabs("option", "selected");
        $("#tabsinner").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
    });
```

and the html :

```
<div id="vtabs">
<ul id="verticalUl">
    <li><a href="#vtab-1">Outer Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#vtab-2">Outer Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#vtab-3">Outer Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="vtab-1">
    <div id="tabsinner" >
        <ul id="horizontalUl">
            <li><a href="#tabsinner-1">Inner Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabsinner-2">Inner Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabsinner-3">Inner Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabsinner-1">
            <h2>Content heading 1</h2>
            <button type="button" class="nexttab">Next Tab</button>
        </div>
        <div id="tabsinner-2">
            <h2>Content heading 2</h2>
            <button type="button" class="nexttab">Next Tab</button>
        </div>
        <div id="tabsinner-3">
            <h2>Content heading 3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="vtab-2">
    <h2>Vertical Tab Content heading 2</h2>       
</div>
<div id="vtab-3">
    <h2>Vertical Tab Content heading 3</h2>
</div>
```

Now I am using vertical tabs to the left side and than more horizontal tabs inside the outer tabs (nested tabs). Now I think that this is not the issue since I removed the outer ones and it still doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems I can see, the class of the next button is `nexttab` and the option to use is [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)

```
$(".nexttab").click(function () {
    var selected = $("#tabsinner").tabs("option", "active");
    $("#tabsinner").tabs("option", "active", selected + 1);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rm0y7sdf/1/)

Comment: yeappp it worked, although I entered the wrong class on the example, just had to change selected to active. Thanks a lot!!